# Почему входит в массив?

Tags: php

```
$s="d[уйц12344l]";
$c=[
    0,1,2,3,4,5
];
in_array($s,$c)===true?$res='входит':$res="нет";
echo $res;
```

Почему выводит "входит"?

Comment: Потому что сравнивается число и строка. [Подробнее](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.operators.comparison.php)

Comment: Зачем вообще писать `in_array($s,$c)===true`? Когда функция `in_array` возвращает и так `bool in_array`? Смотрите внимательнее документацию, в данном случае `===true` лишнее и ко всему еще и строку с числом сравниваете.

Comment: @And сказали А говорите и Б. почему не `$res = ... ?...  : ...` а `... ? $res = .. : $res = ...`?

Comment: @u_mulder Ну а почему он находит? Если даже типы разные?

Comment: Вы документ по ссылке __до конца__ дочитайте.

Comment: потому что строка `$s` приводится к нулю перед сравнением

Comment: Если усугублять то уж сразу `echo ... ? 'a' : 'b';`

Comment: @And ===true с preg_match осталось) стереть.

Comment: @teran в ответе отпишите. Это ответ на вопрос. Это in_array делает?

Comment: `preg_match` возвращает тип `int`, зачем его сравнивать с `bool`? Странный вы какой-то.

Comment: @And http://php.net/manual/ru/function.preg-match.php прочтите там где внимание.

Comment: @And а вы где тут нашли `preg_match` или вообще использование регулярных выражений?

Comment: @teran Мой коммент выше.

Comment: Скорее это уже будет не совсем правильная логика использования, раз будут внимания.

Comment: @teran, это может потребоваться при присваивании значения переменной, для дальнейших использований. К примеру самое обычное использование: `$m = ['a' => 'a'];
$a = 'a';
$b = 'b';
$n = 'n';
echo (in_array($a, $m) ? ($a = 'c') : $a) ? ($a === $b ? $a : $a . ',' . $b) : $n;`

Comment: @And это трындец какой-то, а не "обычное использование"

Comment: @teran, До кучи. `$e = 'e';
echo (0===($t = 0) && ($c = 3) && ($m = ['a' => 'a']) && ($a = 'a') && ($b = 'b') && (($t = 3) && $c === $t)) ? ((in_array($a, $m) ? ($a = $b) : $a) ? ($a === $b ? $a : $a . ',' . $b . ' = ' . $c) : $e) : $e;`

Comment: @And сочувствую вашему работодателю, и тем, кому придется сопровождать ваш код в дальнейшем

Comment: @teran, причем тут это? Суть в другом, что это работает и так делать можно, а если ты не силен в этом, тут уже другой вопрос.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В вашем коде используется сравнение элементов без учёта их типов. При этом массив содержит числа, а искомое значение - строка. В результате чего строка приводится также к  целому числу. Правила приведения в данном случае говорят, что `$s` будет равно `0`. А после данного преобразования 0 уже находится в массиве.

Вы можете использовать третий параметр функции `in_array` для учета типов операндов, тогда вместо простого `==` будет использоваться `===`

```
$s = "d[уйц12344l]";
$c = [ 0,1,2,3,4,5 ];
echo in_array($s, $c, true) ? 'входит' : "нет";
```

которое даст ответ "нет"

Comment: Т.е строка $s = "d[уйц12344l]"; после преобразования иметь тип string ($s ="0")?

Comment: @doox911 когда вы строку сравниваете с числом, она приводится к числу. Правила приведения таковы, что `"123asd345435~="` приведется к числу `123`, то есть будут взяты первые цифры. В вашей строке ведуших цифр нет, поэтому она будет равна 0 (`int $s = 0`). Дальнейшие сравнения при поиске в массиве будут происходить между этим нулем и тем, что в массиве.

Comment: Тогда я не понял, почему при флаге сравнения типов даст ответ "нет"?

Comment: Потому что приведение типов __не__ выполняется, и сравнение строки с числом ясное дело выдаст false.